# Damped systems - deriving equation

Tags: control-theory

I am having some troubles deriving the formula for the roots for different types systems.. I am not quite sure if they are correct (pretty sure they aren't).

$y(s) = \frac{s+2\zeta\omega_n}{s^2 + 2\zeta\omega_ns +\omega_n^2}$

I don't see how i should derive them for different scenarios

In my book it is stated that  for an underdamped system $\zeta < 1$ is the roots
S1,2 = $-\zeta\omega_n \pm i\omega_n \sqrt{1-\zeta^2}$ which i don't get.

I've derived it to be
$\frac{-2\zeta\omega_n \pm \sqrt{4\zeta^2\omega_n^2- 4\omega_n^2}}{2}$

I don't see how the hell they got the other one, and how they are for the other cases!!??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, just look at the root!

$$\frac{-2\zeta\omega_n \pm \sqrt{4\zeta^2\omega_n^2- 4\omega_n^2}}{2}
=\frac{-2\zeta\omega_n \pm 2\omega_n\sqrt{\zeta^2- 1}}{2}$$
And that is:
$$-\zeta\omega_n \pm i\omega_n\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}$$
Elaboration:
$$\sqrt{4\zeta^2\omega_n^2- 4\omega_n^2}=\sqrt{4\omega_n^2(\zeta^2-1)}=$$
$$\sqrt{4\omega_n^2}\sqrt{\zeta^2-1}=2\omega_n\sqrt{\zeta^2-1}$$
Different scenarios:

- $\zeta=0$ no dampening, formula $S_{12}=i\omega_n$
- $\zeta<1$ dampening, solution is complex, oscillatory
- $\zeta=1$ critical dampening, the formula will be $S_{12}=-\zeta\omega_n$
- $\zeta>1$ overdamped, two different real roots, will take longer to converge than criticaly dampened, formula $S_{12}=-\zeta\omega_n \pm \omega_n\sqrt{\zeta^2-1}$

Comment: Well.. that makes sense, but how come for the other cases, they do not exist in my text book..

Comment: The other cases arise when you put $\zeta$=1 for crit dampened, and $\zeta$>1 for the overdamping. And well I forgot to put the imaginary unity in front of it.

Comment: They are just cases, $\zeta$ is the dampening factor. For different $\zeta$ you will get different behaviour. The easiest way to see this is by putting the values of $\zeta$ for the different scenarios in the formula, and looking how it changes.

Comment: Yes.. I know that the other cases arrives for different values of the damping ratio, but do they have a formula like the underdamped here? and $i$ is stil missing from the $4\omega_n^2$

Comment: The $i$ comes from changing $\sqrt{\zeta^2-1}$ to $i\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}$, as we take the root of $-1$ out as a factor. I'll add something to the answer for the different scenarios.

Comment: Ahh... ofCourse, $\sqrt{\zeta^2 - 1} =>\sqrt{-1(1 -\zeta^2)} => \sqrt{-1} \sqrt{(1 -\zeta^2)}  $

Comment: Yes, that's it. I need to do something else. If you still have questions I can answer them later.

Comment: until now it's all, Thanks for your help :)